# How do I renew an SSL certificate using ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have an application in its own resource group in Azure that was provisioned using Azure Resource Management templates.

When I try to replace the SSL certficate by changing the pfxBlob to the base64 string of the renewed certificate .PFX file and then deploy the template everything appears to work correctly.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
  "name": "[variables('appService_name')]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
  "location": "[parameters('resourceLocation')]",
  "properties": {
    "pfxBlob": "[parameters('sslCertificateData')]",
    "password": "[parameters('sslCertificatePassword')]"
  }
}
```

There are no errors, but when I check in the Azure portal, the certificate has not been updated and continues to show the details of the old certificate.

I can manually upload the certificate through the Azure portal (although it appears as a second certificate), so I'm certain there is no issue with the certificate.

Is it possible to overwrite an existing certificate using ARM templates?

Comment: you probably need to add it as a second certificate...

Comment: Could it be somehow related to [this bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/8056/) that is open as on today?  

Also, If you use a certificate from _KeyVault_, try using the "**keyVaultId**" property that points to the latest certificate (you'll of course have 2 certificates listed on the keyvault/portal as you stated already). Example usage [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/app-service-certificate-standard/azuredeploy.json/)